# Fill columns independently

Tags: python-polars

I have a python class with two data class, first one is a polars time series, second one a list of string.

In a dictionary, a mapping from string and function is provided, for each element of the string is associated a function that returns a polars frame (of one column).

Then there is a function class that create a polars data frame with first column the time series and the other columns are created with this function.

Columns are all independent.

Is there a way to create this data frame in parallel?

Here I try to define a minimal example:

```
class data_frame_constr():
    function_list: List[str]
    time_series: pl.DataFrame

    def compute_indicator_matrix(self) -> pl.DataFrame:
        for element in self.function_list:
            self.time_series.with_column(
                [
                    mapping[element] # here is where we construct columns with the loop and mapping[element] is a custom function that returns a pl column
                ]
            )
        return self.time_series
```

For example, function_list = ["square", "square_root"].

Time frame is a column time series, I need to create square and square root (or other custom complex functions, identified by its name) columns, but I know the list of function only at runtime, specified in the constructor.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of what you have as input and what result you desire?

Comment: I've seen List context but I'm not sure it fits my problem.

Comment: Of course, do not worry about the side effect of change the class variable in example, it's only an example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`with_columns`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.with_columns.html) context to provide a list of expressions, as long as the expressions are independent.  (Note the plural: with_column**s**.)  Polars will attempt to run all expressions in the list in parallel, even if the list of expressions is generated dynamically at run-time.

```py
def mapping(func_str: str) -> pl.Expr:
    '''Generate Expression from function string'''
    ...


def compute_indicator_matrix(self) -> pl.DataFrame:
    expr_list = [mapping(next_funct_str)
                 for next_funct_str in self.function_list]
    self.time_series = self.time_series.with_columns(expr_list)
    return self.time_series
```

One note: it is a common misconception that Polars is a generic Threadpool that will run any/all code in parallel.  This is not true.

If any of your expressions call external libraries or custom Python bytecode functions (e.g., using a `lambda` function, `map`, `apply`, etc..), then your code will be subject to the Python GIL, and will run single-threaded - **no matter how you code it**.  Thus, try to use only the Polars expressions to achieve your objectives (rather than calling external libraries or Python functions.)

For example, try the following. (Choose a value of `nbr_rows` that will stress your computing platform.)  If we run the code below, it will run in parallel because everything is expressed using Polars expressions without calling external libraries or custom Python code.  The result is **embarassingly** parallel performance.

```py
nbr_rows = 100_000_000
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'col1': pl.repeat(2, nbr_rows, eager=True),
})

df.with_columns([
    pl.col('col1').pow(1.1).alias('exp_1.1'),
    pl.col('col1').pow(1.2).alias('exp_1.2'),
    pl.col('col1').pow(1.3).alias('exp_1.3'),
    pl.col('col1').pow(1.4).alias('exp_1.4'),
    pl.col('col1').pow(1.5).alias('exp_1.5'),
])
```

However, if we instead write the code using `lambda` functions that call Python bytecode, then it will run **very** slowly.

```py
import math
df.with_columns([
    pl.col('col1').apply(lambda x: math.pow(x, 1.1)).alias('exp_1.1'),
    pl.col('col1').apply(lambda x: math.pow(x, 1.2)).alias('exp_1.2'),
    pl.col('col1').apply(lambda x: math.pow(x, 1.3)).alias('exp_1.3'),
    pl.col('col1').apply(lambda x: math.pow(x, 1.4)).alias('exp_1.4'),
    pl.col('col1').apply(lambda x: math.pow(x, 1.5)).alias('exp_1.5'),
])
```

Comment: Thanks. I see your point about expressions to parallelise my code.
I have another question: If I write inside mapping only function in polars context, will the result inside with_columns be embarassingly parallel?
I have the problem that I can know only at runtime expressions to use.

Comment: Yes, the `with_columns` context is designed to run every expression in the list in parallel, even if the the list of expressions is generated dynamically at run-time.  (I should have been more explicit about that in my answer.  I'll add that.)

Comment: Thanks. It's clear.
I have another question: you said to use only the Polars expressions without calling external libraries. What about numpy? Can I use numpy constants? For example pi and e? User guide says that polars is compatible with ufuncs, also for constants?

Comment: You can use numpy constants without slowing down Polars significantly.  For example, in the example calculation above, you can substitute `numpy.pi` and `numpy.e` (e.g., `pl.col('col1').pow(numpy.pi).alias('exp_...')`, and there will be no discernible slowdown in the calculations.